# function NameError not defined

Tags: python

I am new to python and I get this error in my script below:

```
NameError: name 'csv_name_for' is not defined

def cvs_name_for(date):
    return "abuse_{0}.csv".format(date) 

def export_to_csv(complaints, date):    
    with open("{0}/{1}".format(CSV_DIR, csv_name_for(date)), "w") as csvfile:
    # do stuff
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function name is `cvs...` and you call `csv...`.
Fixed:

```
def csv_name_for(date):
    return "abuse_{0}.csv".format(date) 

def export_to_csv(complaints, date):    
    with open("{0}/{1}".format(CSV_DIR, csv_name_for(date)), "w") as csvfile:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Doh! What an idiot I am lol